# Angular2 service testing : inject a dependency with beforeEach

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine

I am testing services with an `Http` dependency. Every test looks like this :

```
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ValidationService } from './validation.service';
import { HttpModule, Http, Response, ResponseOptions, RequestOptions, Headers, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';

describe('DashboardService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule],
      providers: [
        ValidationService,
        { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend }
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should ...',
    inject([ValidationService, XHRBackend],
      (service: ValidationService, mockBackEnd: MockBackend) => {
        mockBackEnd.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
          connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
            body: JSON.stringify('content')
          })));
        });
      }));
      // assertions ...
});
```

As you can see, I need to inject the BackEnd mock at every it.

Is it possible to use a `beforeEach` to inject the dependency before every test ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a beforeEach to inject the dependency before every test ?

Sure you could.

```
let service;

beforeEach(inject([Service], (svc) => {
  service = svc;
}))
```

Though you could also just get the service from the `TestBed`, which is also an injector

```
let service;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    ...
  })

  service = TestBed.get(Service);
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try both ways to see what fits me best.

Comment: is there a way to inject Service without using TestBed setup?

Comment: @PriteshAcharya See this https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/dependency-injection/

Comment: I get the error `Error: StaticInjectorError[Service]: NullInjectorError: No provider for Service!`

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic did you configure it in the TestBed? You still need to do that.

Comment: The first example has no TestBed.

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic it's assumed

Comment: By the way, make sure to import the `inject` from `@angular/core/testing`

Comment: AFAIK, the second, `TestBed` approach only works if the Service is provided in the root.

Comment: It's assumed.. okay. But it'd be very much clearer if we could actually see it.